# python function is not calling for every n seconds using threading.timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

```
Class A:

  def get_data(self,arg1):

    ........

  def test(self):

    self.timer = threading.Timer(1,self.get_data, args=(arg1,))

    self.timer.start()
    ......

    self.timer.cancel()
```

While trying to call get_data(), for every one second, it is not calling.

Other part of the code is executing. No sytax or indentation errors are

observed. Please let me know the missing thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `threading.Timer` only calls the target function once (as documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects).

What you really want to do is create a `threading.Thread` instance whose target is a function with an endless loop that calls `get_data` and sleeps for 1 second.

And you want that loop to stop when a certain condition is reached -- like a `running` flag set to `False`. That way, you can *stop* the loop once you no longer need it to run.